# find all edges for a result set of nodes

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

I have a query that returns a set of nodes, like this:

```
g.V().as("a","node").has("prop1", true).out().as("b","node").hasLabel("device")
.in().as("c","node").hasLabel("lbl1").has("prop1", false).select("a","b","c").limit(200)
```

Now I want to return all these nodes and any edge between them as my result. I tried the following but it always comes back empty:

```
g.V().(....)
.select("a","b","c").limit(200)
.select("node").dedup().fold().as('all')
.unfold().as('start').bothE().as('edge').otherV().as('end')
.where(within('all'))
.select('start', 'edge', 'end').dedup()
```

unfortunately this always comes back empty. I think my where filter is incorrect. How do I filter the result for only those where node "c" is one of those in "a"?

I want to keep this generic so I can use it to process multiple different queries that all return a set of nodes.

Answer (score 3):

For this query, you should check that out vertex is in the set of the beginning vertex. So you should first fold() the start set and then check against it with within() predicate inside where
Here is query for example `g =  TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()`

```
g.V().limit(3).fold().as('all').
    unfold().as('a').outE().as('b').otherV().as('c').
    where(within('all')).
    select('a', 'b', 'c')
```

See 2nd example here: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#where-step

Comment: thanks this helped. I think my biggest issue was that I used `select` instead of `aggregate` which meant I only received a collection of the end nodes, because `select` replaces the previous store.